# How to obtain the next step in the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please help me understand step $(*)$ below. How is this step obtained from the previous. The derivative has been removed so do we perform integration? I've tried integration by parts, but do not get anything similar.

For the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt} =ax,$$

There are only solutions of the form $x(t)=ke^{at}$. To see this, let $u(t)$ be any solution and compute the derivative of $u(t)e^{-at}:$

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(u(t)e^{−at}) &=u'(t)e^{−at} +u(t)(−ae^{−at}) \\&=au(t)e^{−at} −au(t)e^{−at} \quad \quad \quad\quad(*)\\&=0
\end{align}

Comment: I think x should be u instead in the differential equation. Then the step is just substitution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u(t)=ke^{at}$ then $u'(t)=ake^{at}=a\cdot u(t)$ is what this method is using.

If you struggle to follow this method however, noting this is a Variable Separable Equation and solving is much more intuitive in my opinion.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=ax$$
$$\to \frac{dx}{x} = a\  dt$$
$$\to \int \frac{dx}{x} = \int a \ dt$$
$$\to \ln x =at + C$$
$$\to x=e^{at+C}=e^Ce^{at}=ke^{at}$$
Since $e^C$ is just a constant.

Answer (score 1):

By assumption, $u (t) $ is a solution of differential equation. Hence $u'(t)=a\cdot u (t) $.